# Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in Magento 2.1 - Should we do it?

Tags: magento-2.1

Magento 2.1.9 has a built-in option to enable HSTS.

I read in OWASP official wiki that enabling HSTS for a domain is not something to be done without thorough thinking over, because preloading headers with HSTS can have permanent consequences on how the domain is served to users.

So, I wonder, if HSTS is recommended or will it only complicate things with potential disruptive effects on a website? What is your advice?

Comment: the only problem in magento - they set incomplete header... better to set this header at server level, and with preload option. provided you have full https  website

Comment: By "full https" website, you mean that every page on the website is loaded over HTTPS, is this correct?